# assembly.GetTypes() vs assembly.DefinedTypes.Select(t => t.AsType());

Tags: c#, reflection

```
public static IEnumerable<Type> GetAccessibleTypes(this Assembly assembly)
    {
        try
        {
#if NET40
            return assembly.GetTypes();
#else
            return assembly.DefinedTypes.Select(t => t.AsType());
#endif
        }
        catch (ReflectionTypeLoadException ex)
        {
            // The exception is thrown if some types cannot be loaded in partial trust.
            // For our purposes we just want to get the types that are loaded, which are
            // provided in the Types property of the exception.
            return ex.Types.Where(t => t != null);
        }
    }
```

What are differences between `assembly.GetTypes()` and `assembly.DefinedTypes.Select(t => t.AsType())`?

Original code:
https://entityframework.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/Common/AssemblyExtensions.cs

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [MSDN documentation](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.definedtypes): "The `DefinedTypes` property is comparable to the `Assembly.GetTypes` method, except that the `DefinedTypes` property returns a collection of `TypeInfo` objects, and the `Assembly.GetTypes` method returns an array of `Type` objects."

Not terribly useful at first sight. Looking further into the [documentation on `TypeInfo`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.typeinfo?view=netframework-4.8) is much more informative: "A `TypeInfo` object represents the type definition itself, whereas a `Type` object represents a reference to the type definition. Getting a `TypeInfo` object forces the assembly that contains that type to load. In comparison, you can manipulate `Type` objects without necessarily requiring the runtime to load the assembly they reference."

The reason for this is outlined in [a microsoft blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/evolving-the-reflection-api/), outlining the changes to the reflection API introduced in .NET 4.5. The main difference is that the `Type` now no longer necessarily forces the loading of the type, and works much more as a slim handle into the type metadata, hence making introspection much lighter.

Answer (score 1):

At a minimum, the returned objects are different types, with one being an array of `Type`s and the other being a generic `IQueryable<Type>`.

Here is the code from Assembly.GetTypes()

```
[ResourceExposure(ResourceScope.None)]
[ResourceConsumption(ResourceScope.Machine | ResourceScope.Assembly, ResourceScope.Machine | ResourceScope.Assembly)] 
public virtual Type[] GetTypes() 
{
    Module[] m = GetModules(false); 

    int iNumModules = m.Length;
    int iFinalLength = 0;
    Type[][] ModuleTypes = new Type[iNumModules][]; 

    for (int i = 0; i < iNumModules; i++) 
    { 
        ModuleTypes[i] = m[i].GetTypes();
        iFinalLength += ModuleTypes[i].Length; 
    }

    int iCurrent = 0;
    Type[] ret = new Type[iFinalLength]; 
    for (int i = 0; i < iNumModules; i++)
    { 
        int iLength = ModuleTypes[i].Length; 
        Array.Copy(ModuleTypes[i], 0, ret, iCurrent, iLength);
        iCurrent += iLength; 
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Comment: [`DefinedTypes`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.assembly.definedtypes.aspx) is an `IEnumerable<Type>` not an `IQueryable<Type>`.